localization/internationalization in angular using xlf file
https://angular.dev/guide/i18n
i am localizing an angular application using xlf file which is in angular document..same steps..the problem i am facing is that when i refresh the page it shows 404 error also when i change the language in another component it redirects to login page but i want it to stay in same component. how can i fix it??
   <mat-button-toggle-group [hideSingleSelectionIndicator]="true" class="toggle-btn-grp montserrat">
              
                <mat-button-toggle (click)="changeLanguage('en-US')" [checked]="siteLocale === 'en-US'">English</mat-button-toggle>
                <mat-button-toggle (click)="changeLanguage('da-DK')" [checked]="siteLocale === 'da-DK'">Danish</mat-button-toggle>
            </mat-button-toggle-group>

 changeLanguage(language: string) {

    const currentPath = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
this.router.navigate([`/${language}/${currentPath}`]);

  }

constructor( ) {
    this.siteLocale = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  }

i have multiple components hence when i add language en-us/a/b and then try to change the language from component b the page redirects to en-us/a
